# Can’t connect Project to Simulator

Tags: xcode

I have an issue that has been posted to this board on many occasions.  There seems to be several answers, but most of them are for older versions of XCode which are no longer applicable as folder location have changed etc.

XCode was working perfectly and then out of the blue, when I run the simulator I’m getting a dialog with the message:

> Could not attach pid: “xxxx”

I’ve tried rebooting, clean build folder, deleting the app from the simulator, deleting derived data, etc.  Nothing seems to do the trick

The issue isn’t isn’t project specific as I create a new project and get the same error.  I’m on XCode 11.3.1

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I saw the same while testing Xcode 11.3.1 on a slow machine running Mojave. Xcode is unable to attach to the ios Simulator process when started for debugging.

I don't know what caused it, but a workaround is to manually attach the debugger via the Xcode menu : "Debug" -> "Attach to Process" -> then select your process, probably already listed at the top unde "Likely Targets".

Answer (score 0):

saw this on a [forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/109426) `sudo /usr/sbin/DevToolsSecurity -enable`

Comment: Try reverting to a old version

Comment: An old version of the project or XCode?

Comment: seems to be a xcode issue, so I would recommend downgrading xcode to see if the issue persists

Comment: Ok.. I just closed my laptop went to lunch, opened it and everything is working now.  I rebooted the laptop several times before posting to Stack overflow..  No idea.  Thanks for your help.